# How can I obtain the index of the selected shiny radioButton

Tags: shiny

I am creating dynamic radioButtons and want to most easily reference the chosen value

```
radioButtons("choice","Select",c("A","B","C"))
```

If a user selects option A, I want to obtain the value,1: B,2 etc.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Found the best way was

```
options <- c("A","B","C")
radioButtons("choice","Select",options)
```

Then in a reactive

```
colChoice <- match(input$choice,options)
```

This provides the index

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
radioButtons("choice", "Select", c("A"=1,"B"=2,"C"=3))
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.